# Foreach con break

Tags: php, laravel

Puede que suene tonta la pregunta, pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo...

Resulta que quiero hacer un grafico con highcharts, al momento de colocar los nombres de los datos a medir, los quiero recorrer en un foreach para no estar anotando uno por uno los nombres y demases, busco y no encuentro solución!

Dejo parte del código como referencia

```
series: [{
                    name: [<?php foreach($datosCompletos_norte as $nombre) :?>[<?= $nombre['nombre_nortes'] ?>,
                        <?php endforeach; ?>]],
                    data: [<?php foreach($datosCompletos_norte as $datos) :?>[<?= $datos['cantidad_salida_norte'] ?>],
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    ]
                }
                // },
                // {
                //     name: 'Entrada Norte',
                //     data: [<?php foreach($datosCompletos_norte as $datos) :?>[<?= $datos['cantidad_entrada_norte'] ?>],
                //         <?php endforeach ?>
                //     ]
                // }
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes evitar hacer iteraciones dentro del mismo código ya que no será muy legible. En todo caso te recomiendo que, dado que estás usando Laravel conviertas tu arreglo en un collection:

$collection = collect($datosCompletos_norte);

y utilices el [método pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck) sobre el collection para extraer la lista de "nombres" que requieres.

Tú código quedaría de esta manera:

```
$datosCompletos = collection($datosCompletos_norte);
series: [{
         name: $datosCompletos->pluck('nombre_nortes'),
         data: $datosCompletos->pluck('cantidad_salida_norte),
]}
```

Como puedes darte cuenta conseguiras un código más legible y mantenible.